WebRTC: Increase of jitterBufferDelay in Chrome
In our webrtc application we experience too high values of jitterBufferDelay which causes out of sync audio and video.
Some users reported this issues with out of sync video.
I can recreate the behavior only in chrome (124) with a specific device. When I turn off the camera the jitterBufferDelay values for the audio stream are fine. When I turn the cam on, jitterBufferDelay/jitterBufferEmittedCount_in_ms] will spike up to 5000ms which creates a long delay and sync with video is lost.
The cpu values seem to be fine.
Where should I start with debugging?

If you have a stable reproduction using https://www.chromium.org/developers/bisect-builds-py/ to identify the commit that caused this and filing a bug is the way to go

Accordingly to this Google Chrome Bug It seems it should be fixed (requires the browser to be restarted to get the experiment disabled)
https://issues.chromium.org/issues/340194451#comment34
